# Performance of C++ 17 tree using optional<unique_ptr<Node>>?

Tags: c++, c++17

I really like the code style that comes with using something like this

```
class Node {
public:
  std::optional<std::unique_ptr<Node>> left;
  std::optional<std::unique_ptr<Node>> right;
  Key key;
  Val val;
};
```

How will performance compare to a C style tree using malloc/delete and nullptr checks? Will there be any performance hit?

Comment: Why optional of unique_ptr? A unique_ptr do the job as it can be nullable through `nullptr`

Comment: What would be the difference between a null optional and a non-null optional of a null pointer? Is there a meaningful difference between "no subtree" and "an empty subtree"?

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::optional<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` would lead to some loss of space and possibly an extra boolean check at run-time.

But `unique_ptr` has a "non-owned" state, in which case it "contains" a `nullptr`, which should be enough to express the no-value state.

```
class Node {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
  Key key;
  Val val;
};
```

There is even a convenience [`operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool) to check if there is an associated value or not.

The code above should compile with no performance loss compared to a raw pointers solution.